# Enter Data in linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to insert every character of a message into a linked list, but I don't understand where I am going wrong

I'm allocating right, but at the time of printing the message, is giving error

Can someone help me?

As Struct

```
struct mensagem{
    char msg;
    char chave;
};


struct elemento{
    struct mensagem dados;
    struct elemento *prox;
};
typedef struct elemento* Lista;
typedef struct elemento Elem;
```

The functions- Build list , insert element and print list

```
Lista* cria_lista(){
    Lista* li = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    if(li != NULL)
        *li = NULL;
    return li;
}
int insere_lista_final(Lista* li, struct mensagem al){
    if(li == NULL)
        return 0;
    Elem *no;
    no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    if(no == NULL)
        return 0;
    no->dados = al;
    no->prox = NULL;
    if((*li) == NULL){//lista vazia: insere início
        *li = no;
    }else{
        Elem *aux;
        aux = *li;
        while(aux->prox != NULL){
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        aux->prox = no;
    }
    return 1;
}
void imprime_lista(Lista* li){
    if(li == NULL)
        return 0;
    Elem* no = *li;
    while(no != NULL){
        printf("%c1",no->dados.msg);

        no = no->prox;
    }
}
```

Int main

```
int main()
{
    int mod_exec=1,i=0;
    char c;
    struct mensagem al;
    Lista* li = cria_lista();
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
            {
                insere_lista_final(li,al);
                imprime_lista(li);
            }
    return 0 ;

}
typedef struct elemento* Lista;
typedef struct elemento Elem;

Lista* cria_lista(){
    Lista* li = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    if(li != NULL)
        *li = NULL;
    return li;
}
int insere_lista_final(Lista* li, struct mensagem al){
    if(li == NULL)
        return 0;
    Elem *no;
    no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    if(no == NULL)
        return 0;
    no->dados = al;
    no->prox = NULL;
    if((*li) == NULL){//lista vazia: insere início
        *li = no;
    }else{
        Elem *aux;
        aux = *li;
        while(aux->prox != NULL){
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        aux->prox = no;
    }
    return 1;
}
void imprime_lista(Lista* li){
    if(li == NULL)
        return 0;
    Elem* no = *li;
    while(no != NULL){
        printf("%c1",no->dados.msg);

        no = no->prox;
    }
}
```

Int main

```
int main()
{
    int mod_exec=1,i=0;
    char c;
    struct mensagem al;
    Lista* li = cria_lista();
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
            {
                insere_lista_final(li,al);
                imprime_lista(li);
            }
    return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a `main` function? Also, trigger warnings and treat them as errors; and there is no need to cast when using `malloc`

Comment: Malloc-ing sizeof(lista) is probably not what you want since lista is a pointer.  You probably want to define lista as:    typedef struct elemento Lista;

Comment: I'd strongly suggest against using your local language in source code. For example the code you've posted is easily twice as hard to understand for someone who doesn't know the language you've used.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `main` function with properly initialized variables didn't lead me to errors:

```c
int main(void)
{
    Lista *l = cria_lista();
    struct mensagem m1 = { .msg = 'a', .chave = 'b'};
    struct mensagem m2 = { .msg = 'c', .chave = 'd'};

    insere_lista_final(l,m1);
    insere_lista_final(l,m2);
    imprime_lista(l);

    return 0;
}
```

Be sure your trigger warnings flags when compiling.